# Laravel get route list by request Type methods

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 6.1 . I am trying do dynamic permission for user for add,edit ,delete and view .so trying to get route list from laravel router using following method

```
$routes = [];

foreach (Route::getRoutes()->getIterator() as $route){

    $routes[] = $route->uri;

}
```

This will return all route url list but problem here is for paramter routes list it has below

```
post-detail/{categoryId}/{postid}
```

How i can compare in middleware whether url is matching to this route .

Also is it possible to get route type along with route list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Route` object has a `matches` method to see if the request matches the route which can also check the HTTP method:

```
$route->matches($request, true);
```

[laravel/framework 6.x - Illuminate\Routing\Route@matches](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php#L266)

You can also ask the Route Collection to find a matching route for the current Request:

```
$route = Route::getRoutes()->match($request);
```

Though this would just be the current route: `$request->route()`

[laravel/framework 6.x - Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection@match](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php#L157)

Though I am not really sure what you are trying to do just by iterating through the routes.

---

The HTTP methods the Route responds to can be retrieved via `$route->methods()`.

The HTTP method of the current Request can be accessed via `$request->method()`.

Comment: @lagbox.Thank you.is it possible to get route request type.since i have route called Route::any .so i can route request type in db and compare request type

Comment: @lagbox.one more query.  dd(Route::getRoutes()); will print  Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection {#37 ▼
  #routes: array:7 [▼
    "GET" => array:123 [▶]
    "HEAD" => array:123 [▶]
    "POST" => array:100 [▶]
    "PUT" => array:79 [▶]
    "PATCH" => array:79 [▶]
    "DELETE" => array:91 [▶]
    "OPTIONS" => array:79 [▶]  .How to get these route method lsit

Comment: `Route::getRoutes()->getRoutesByMethod()`, then you have an array with indexes for the method type